# Color all even items in a different color in a result table shown in a view

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

I am building an MVC-app in which items are displayed in a table.

Here's an example of table included in a view:

```
<table id="itemsID">
    <tr>
        <th>Obj Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Prize</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].m_ObjName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].m_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].m_Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].m_Size)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].m_Prize)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model[i].m_ObjID}) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Model[i].m_ObjID}) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model[i].m_ObjID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

What I am trying to do is color each item in the for loop which number is even / odd. Up to now I've wrote a short javascript which partially works:

```
$("#results tr:even").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");;
```

Simple, yet evidently it affects ALL the items in the page, not the items displayed in the for loop. How can I target those items specifically?

**EDIT**

Based on everyone's kind explanations, I have made modifications to the code up there. Now ALL the even tr in the result list are affected, including the first `<tr>` right under the `<table>`, but I would like it to be ignored, how could I do this? I have tried to put the ID solely on the `<tr>` in the for loop, but it does not work...

Comment: m_ and s_ are used in C++ where "this" and "<classname>::" are not mandatory, but they are no use in PHP, imo. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CSS3

css3 may help you. Lead to w3schools and take a read about [the ":nth-of-type" pseudo selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp), or see it in action [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-of-type_odd_even)

I would recomend the solution 1 as i think is a better practice.

**Note**: Both solutions assume the "itemID" will be not the same all the time, so we've to base the element selection on other criteria. This is the reason i added the "item-table" class to the `<table>` tag.

**HTML for both solutions**

```
<table id="itemsID" class="item-table">
  <tr>
    <!-- header field names go here  -->
  </tr>
  @for (int i = 0; i < Item.Count; i++)
  {
    <tr>
        <!-- each item's properties go here -->
    </tr>
  }
```

### Solution 1: do it on the stylesheet (recomended)

```
.item-table tr + tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    /* styles for the even rows */
}
.item-table tr + tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    /* styles for the odd rows */
}
```

**Note**: `tr + tr` selects all the `<tr>` tags after the first one. This is useful to skip the header and apply other style to it. For more info [see the element + element reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp).

**Tip**: you could also apply styles only to the header  with the [:first-child pseudo selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp), as follows:

```
.item-table tr:first-child {
    /* styles for the header row */
}
```

### Solution 2: modify your selector on the jQuery query

```
$('table.item-table tr:even').css({ /* some styles here */ })
```

Comment: I will try this and get you back on the results.

Comment: @HerveS i hope it was useful

Comment: What language is this by the way ? @Html.ActionLink stuff ?

Comment: @HerveS i added a bit more info, maybe you want to know a bit more about css selectors or maybe you want to style the header

Comment: @Virus721 not the same stuff. Solution 1 is bassed on *CSS*, _Cascading Style Sheets_, you can [read more on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css) and many other sites

Comment: I know what is CSS, thanks XD. I just never saw that `@for (int i = 0; i < Item.Count; i++)
  { <tr></tr> }` What is it ? A PHP templating engine syntax ? Another language than PHP ?

Comment: @Virus721 lol ok, sorry about the missunderstanding. I think it may be some kind of template engine, but i'm not sure. I just used it as the aswered used too, to clarify the explanation.

Comment: @Virus721 - It is part of the asp.net-mvc framework's Razor engine. It uses c# (or visual basic).

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery selector like this:

```
$("#itemsID tr:even").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
```

or just put this in your CSS:

```
#itemsID tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Comment: `:even` is a valid css3 pseudo-selector?

Comment: It's not. It should be `:nth-child(even)`. Updated.

Comment: yeah, anyway it's better not to do this through javascript i think

Answer (score 1):

Give the looped TRs a specific class.

```
<tr class="my_special_row">
    <td></td>... etc
</tr>
```

Then you can target like this:

```
$("tr.my_special_row:even").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
```

Specificity is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways. Using pure CSS, it would be (which I would recommend):

```
#itemsID tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Or you can apply a class to the even rows in your for loop:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    var className = i % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd";

    <tr class="@className">
        ...
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set a different color when `i` is pair or not :

```
color = i % 2 == 0 ? color_1 : color_2
```

Comment: Where would I write this? In the <tr> concerned?

Comment: You could add a class to a <tr> out of two. A color for all <tr> tags, and a color only for the <tr> that have this class which overrides the color set for all <tr>.

Comment: Other guys's jquery solution with :even in the selector seems better though, just keep that in mind when you need to find if something is pair.